# Python format not working properly with floats

Tags: python

I have:

```
    print('Average BTC Left: {:2f} ± {:2f}\tAverage Total Profit: {:2f} ± {:2f}\t Average Ending BTC Price: {:2f} ± {:2f}\t'.format(
        results_df['Current BTC'].mean(), results_df['Current BTC'].std(), results_df['Total Profit'].mean(), results_df['Total Profit'].std(), results_df['Ending BTC Price'].mean(), results_df['Ending BTC Price'].std()))
```

But it prints:

```
Average BTC Left: 0.097777 ± 0.063326   Average Total Profit: 638354.458020 ± 342162.466084      Average Ending BTC Price: 19599.599660 ± 18235.782396
```

Why isn't it restricting the to 2 decimal places?

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/10262890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell the new type of formating now, but old type is:

```
%.2f

print("%.2f" % 78.688411) --> 78.68
```